# How can I remove the quote characters from the first field name when unicodecsv.DictReader is parsing a UTF-8-BOM file in Python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode, python-unicode

The issue is when the class `unicodecsv.DictReader` parses a CSV file's fields when the fields contain quotes and the file is encoded in UTF-8-BOM, the first field retains the quote characters where all consecutive fields have them properly removed.

Example UTF-8-BOM encoded CSV File:

```
"Field1","Field2","Field3"
content1,content2,content3
```

Example Python Code:

```
from unicodecsv import DictReader
filename = "/tmp/test.csv"
with open(filename, mode='r') as read_stream:
     reader = DictReader(read_stream, encoding='utf-8-sig')
     print reader.fieldnames
```

Print Value:

```
['"Field1"','Field2','Field3']
```

Is there a way to have that first field be like the others and have the quote characters removed?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to consume the BOM manually yourself (though I expect the code as written demonstrates an actual bug in the underlying library and should be added to their [issues on github](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv/issues)).  After consuming the BOM, use the utf-8 codec instead.

```
# My test code to write a file with a BOM
import io
filename = "/tmp/test.csv"
with io.open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    f.write(u'''\
"Field1","Field2","Field3"
content1,content2,content3
''')

from unicodecsv import DictReader
with open(filename, mode='r') as read_stream:
     # Consume the BOM
     read_stream.read(3)
     reader = DictReader(read_stream, encoding='utf-8')
     print reader.fieldnames
```

Comment: https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv/issues/81 For completeness. (Discovered this in Aug 2017 and hadn't come across this post or I would have linked it earlier. Here because of a comment on the bug)